# 401 Unauthorized - Permissions Error When Exporting Google Sheet as PDF via Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that will download a specified worksheet from a Google Sheets as a PDF and email it. The request for PDF is failing due to 401, but I'm not sure how to fix (if it's a code issue or a permission I need to set elsewhere). Here's my code:

```js
function download_as_pdf(pdfName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); 
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'') + "export?";
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&format=pdf'     //export as pdf
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&printtitle=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&pagenumbers=false'  //hide page numbers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false'       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      + '&gid='  //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext + sheetId, params)


  // This indicates 401 response
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());

  var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + ".pdf");

}
```

Comment: Does the executing user have permission to export the sheet? It would appear not.

Comment: @tehhowch I think so, but I'm not sure how to verify/adjust that setting. This script is only intended to be used by myself (and I should have full permissions on the worksheet in question). The function is scoped to `@OnlyCurrentDoc` - if I remove that scoping, then Google tells me that the app is unverified.

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, can the Spreadsheet can be copied?

Comment: @Tanaike - the spreadsheet is currently only shared with specific users (basically myself & my wife). Those users have permission to copy, etc. Other parts of my code edit the spreadsheet with read/write operations, copy worksheets, and send emails from `MailApp`. The only part that does not seem to work properly is the export as PDF. Additionally, I am not prompted to grant permissions with this code. I only get the 401 response when I make the `UrlFetchApp` request. Hope this helps!

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds Thank you for replying. In your situation, the Spreadsheet is shared. It can be copied. But it cannot be exported. If my understanding is correct, after it copied the Spreadsheet, how about exporting the copied Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike - Can you elaborate on how/why this would solve the issue? I would think you'd just have the same problem on the new workbook. Is there a potential solution that doesn't involve duplicating the spreadsheet (e.g. adjusting permissions, removing sharing, etc.)? I can give this route a try, but would rather not have to duplicate the doc, export it, delete it, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds I apologize for my poor English skill. 1. In your situation, the Spreadsheet is shared. It can be copied. But it cannot be exported. Is my understanding correct? 2. If my understanding is correct, after it copied the Spreadsheet, how about exporting the copied Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike - the spreadsheet can be manually exported. It cannot be programmatically exported - even by the owner of the workbook.

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds I thought that if the Spreadsheet can be copied, it might convert the copied Spreadsheet to PDF file. So I asked ``In your situation, the Spreadsheet is shared. It can be copied. But it cannot be exported. Is my understanding correct?``. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike - I understand your suggestion. I'm trying to understand what would be different about those permissions?

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds Yes. I thought that the file created by copying might be different permission from the original one, and this might be able to be used as a workaround.